# Using RegeX in Adobe CQ query builder

Tags: aem, query-builder, jcr

Is there any way to use Regular expressions in Query builder. 
Is JCR supports this?
Any pointers on this would be helpful for us.

Thanks in advance.

San

Comment: can you explain what exactly is your use case? if you mean to say for queries then regex is not supported.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, We are planning to create a scheduled job for invalidating cache (dispatcher) for specific resource(s). Regex will help the administrator to define the required resources (application needs to identify the resources based on this RegeX).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this [QueryBuilder API documentation](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/dam/customizing_and_extendingcq5dam/query_builder.html) where to believed as being definitive, then no I would not say there is regex support. However there does seem to be some wildcard support that may be useful. What I would do in this case is try to craft a query around all the properties that you know of about your nodes that can identify them. For example using the debug tool at http://x.x.x.x:4502/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html a query like may give you some ideas

```
type=cq:Page
path=/content/myapp
nodename=*s
1_relativedaterange.property=jcr:content/cq:lastModified
1_relativedaterange.lowerBound=-48h
```

Where I'm looking for pages in my app content, that end is 's', that have been modified in the last 48 hours. You can even filter by resourceType, template, and any other property that can help you find those nodes. You may even consider adding your own just for this query.

Maybe you can have a sling job, where in Java you could iterate the node names (or whatever) and you do have regex, and tag nodes with a meaningful property that you can then use to query using the query builder.

Comment: Thanks Juan, will defanitely give a try with this approach.